# Routing using $stateProvider in angular js , the page is not getting load when tried to route using states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I want to load a page on click of the menu item of my menu but the state gets reflected into my URL of browser and the content of that page doesn't gets loaded, as far as I have studied the tutorial states are declared like that only , my code is not showing me any error also.

here is my route.js file

```
app.config(function config($stateProvider)
{
    $stateProvider.state("index",{
        url:"",
        controller:"MainCtrl",
        templateUrl:"templates/home/home.html"
    }),
        $stateProvider.state("development",{
            controller:"EmployeeCtrl",
            templateUrl:"templates/employee/employee.html"
        });

})
```

This is my list in the home page on whose `href` I have declared states my index state is working perfectly fine.

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#/development">Development</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/design">Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/exercise">Exercise</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/humor">Humor</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Here is the code for the page `employee.html` whose content I want to display when development state is fulfilled.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchText">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="emp in employee.data | filter:searchText"></tr>
        <td>{{emp.firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.lastname}}</td>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you create a plunker?

Comment: Did you try `ui-sref`?

Comment: @Anky did you looked mine answer?

Comment: yup @pankaj its done

Answer (score 1):

State should be differentiated on base of their URL's, so you need to  add `url` parameter in your state, that should be `url: '/development',` for `development` state, so that when URL changes in browser will detect by the `$stateProvider` and then load specified `controller` & `template` by the state definition.

**Code**

```
$stateProvider.state("development",{
    url: '/development',
    controller:"EmployeeCtrl",
    templateUrl:"templates/employee/employee.html"
});
```

You should also use `ui-sref` directive to make sure your `href` has been created properly. You only need to specify `stateName` only in `ui-sref` it will render the value from state `url` like for `ui-sref="development"` it would be `href="#/development"`

Comment: I missed this url part, it should work perfect with it.

Comment: @A.J yes..that's why I added an answer.. :p Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ui-sref` for state routing. Do:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a ui-sref="development">Development</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="design">Design</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="exercise">Exercise</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="humor">Humor</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks its working now its showing me a blank page the code i have done on my page is not shown here

Comment: @AnkitaSingh: it is working now and your code is not shown? I am sorry i didn't get you. Did `ui-sref` help?

Comment: @AnkitaSingh you missed to add `url` in your state..to look at mine answer